# to_tsvector change behaviour

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I have migrated from RDS Aurora PostgreSQL 13.6 to Hetzner Managed DB PostgreSQL 13.8 and this query

`SELECT to_tsvector('I am a heroe') @@ to_tsquery('I & am & a & hero')`
returns FALSE with RDS but TRUE with Hetzner

What could be the reason that bring this change ?

RDS uses pg_catalog.simple and Hetzner pg_catalog.english
But still on Hetzner `SELECT to_tsvector('I am a hero') @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'I & am & a & hero')` returns false

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer must be that the parameter `default_text_search_config` is set to different languages in both databases. It is best to always explicitly specify the language, as in

```
to_tsvector('english', 'I am a heroe')
```

Comment: Thanks I did `SET default_text_search_config TO 'simple'` and I am good now